# Problems with boot time, screen resolution after installing new graphics card

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu

Today I installed a GPU into my computer in anticipation of the new Star Wars Battlefront.  Installation went well, but a couple problems have popped up.

First, boot time is very slow and buggy.  I have an SSD and am used to ~10 second boots.  Now, it gets stuck on the Gigabyte Motherboard screen for nearly 3 minutes, and is slow to proceed to windows after that.  Also, before/during boot, it will only recognize HDMI, and will not send signal through the DVI monitor I tried first.  I read about some possible changes to the BIOS that may solve the problem, but I cannot enter BIOS during boot (or any of the other options).  What can I try to solve this?

My other issue is with the GPU drivers... the one that installed of the included disk leaves my monitors (TVs) looking absolutely beautiful, and perfect fit to the screen.  However, my video games all crash on launch (.exe has stopped working).  When I update to the latest driver using GeForce experience, the screen resolution reverts back the blurriness I was used to, and the edges are off the screen on all four sides (playing with screen resolution does not fix the problem).  However, games run just fine.  I have reverted back and forth between the two drivers twice.  Can you help solve this driver issue?  I don't want to choose between a beautiful screen and being able to play my games.

Here is the equipment I am using.

- Intel Core i5-3470 Ivy Bridge
- GIGABYTE GA-Z77X-UD3H
- Samsung 256GB SSD / Seagate 2TB SSHD
- Cooler Master i700 - 700W PSU
- G.Skill 16GB (2x8) 2400
- GeForce GTX 960 2GB
- Windows 10
- 2x 32" TVs for monitors

Comment: Sometimes the blurriness is the TV side: overscan or scaling may not be working in the same way between drivers. Check the TV settings to see if you can find options for overscan/scaling.

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to the official Gigabyte site and look if there is any new BIOS version you can download, if there is, update your BIOS, I have a GA-990FXA-UD3 (rev. 1.0) that hangs on BIOS screen completely if at that moment 16GB USB pendrive is inserted. 
Second, check all your power and slot connections as issue may lie somewhere there.
And at last if you are sure you have latest BIOS and you have connected everything as it should be, test the card on different OS e.g. Linux and look how it behaves.
Also the issue may lie within BIOS settings, I would advise you to connect your old card (if you have one) and just look through PCI or similar settings.